# android ndk c function return strange value

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, java-native-interface

Android Studio 2.3.2 
Gradle experimental 0.9.2
Last NDK.
I wrote a small function in C that is invoked through JNI in Java but returns a string that precedes characters that should not be there.
This is the C function:

```
    char * text() {
       char * txt = "a";
       char * ret = malloc(strlen(a)+2);
       strcat(ret,txt);
       strcat(ret,"b");
       return ret;
    }
```

This is the JNI C to return to Java

```
    JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL 
      Java_com_myapp_Main_getMsg(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance, jstring var) 
    { 
        char * msg = text();

        return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, msg );
    }
```

This is Java call:

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("myapp");
}
public native String getMsg(String var);

String stringreturnedfromC = getMsg("eee");//eee is not used
```

This show this:

_Main_getMsg**ab**

but should return only "ab".

This is a strange behavior. Why? And how can I get just the right string?

Comment: `strlen(a)` What is a? And what is the len?

Comment: Replace the first strcat() with strcpy().

Comment: #greenapps strlen return length of string and I must use for allocate memory.
I try to replace strcat().

Comment: What is the length i asked. You did not answer my question. And dont you think i know it returns the length of a string? But i see no string! What is variable a i asked. You did not answer.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand your question.
Strlen is called only because it will probably be used in the future and use for testing.

Comment: My god. strlen() will return the length of a string. Now what is it? 1? 4? 56?

Comment: And thanks a lot, replacing with strcpy returned the string correctly. They are really poor in C.

Comment: Who are 'They'? And what is a? And what does it contain? And why would strcat() not do it and strcpy() does?

Comment: Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: And what do I know? Otherwise, I did not ask. I know I do not have a great culture (no one is better to say) in C. I am a beginner.

Comment: As a last remark: every malloc() should finish with a free().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Noticed your function text() is not correct.

Do something like this

```
char * text() {
    char * txt = "a";
    char * ret = (char *)malloc(strlen(txt)); //malloc(strlen(a)+2); is incorrect statment 
    strcat(ret,txt);
    strcat(ret,"b");
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: this return _Main9ab
The @greenapps suggestion is correct.

Comment: Not at all.  Your `malloc()` only returns 1 byte, of indeterminate value.  Using `strcat()` to add a *2-char* string to that (the string `"a"` consists of *two* characters - the `'a'` character and the terminating `'\0'` character) is bad enough, but since the contents of the memory pointed to by `ret` are indeterminate, the final destination of those two characters from `"a"` is unknown.  Then, another `strcat()` tries to add even more to what didn't fit in the first place and wound up being written to some unknown location.

Comment: it will work - even you allocate like (char *)malloc(0); and then strcat(ret,"something longer") - [mac os/ xcode]. Can someone try to run it on windows ?

Comment: Putting a `'\0'` into `ret[0]`just after `malloc` would help. `malloc` doesn't clear memory. That's why `ret` has garbage in it. And that's why doing `strcpy` instead of the first `strcat` helps too.